# How to configure grafana geomap

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to display cpu value in grafana geomap

But, It doesn't work the way I want it to.

I want to set latitude, longitude. but latitude, longitude fields not allow string.

So, I wonder how to configure latitude, longitude fields as I want

This is data query
[image: This is prometheus query]

This is geomap configure

[image]

Finally, I want to set CPU(query), latitude, and longitude in each country.

I'm spending a lot of time on this problem. help me

Answer (score 0):

Group by lat/lot label in your query, first and then use Grafana transformation to change lat/lot string type to number type, so it can be used by geomap panel.